# Can I use constants from C++ also in QML files?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Usually, I can declare a constant in a header file and define it a source file. After that, I can use the constants in every file which have the header included.

Example:

```
// constants.h 
extern const std::string HELLO_WORLD;

// constants.cpp
const std::string HELLO_WORLD = "Hello World";
```

Now I would like to use the constants also in a QML file.

Is there a simple solution to achieve this, something like:
`#inlude constants.h`
or
`import constants.h`?

Or is the only possible way to achive this by creating a class, which has these constants as members, and then making the class accessible in QML?
(Something like described in the Qt Documentation: [Defining QML Types from C++](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html))

Comment: You should just read the documentation, it clearly states what can be exposed to QML and how.

Comment: @dtech I did that and I understood it, it just seemed strange that there is not a "simpler" way in doing that. That's why I'm asking, to be sure that I am not missing an obvious solution.

Comment: Yeah, Qt is full of much easier and better ways to do things that are for some reason deliberately not included in the documentation ;)

Answer (score 7):

Using Qt 5.15's new QML type registration and C++ 17.

**SharedConstants.h**

```
#include <QtQml>

#define SHARED_CONSTANT(type, name, value) \
    static inline const type name = value; \
    Q_PROPERTY(type name MEMBER name CONSTANT)

class SharedConstants : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_UNCREATABLE("Class only exposes constants to QML.")
    QML_ELEMENT
    QML_SINGLETON

public:
    SHARED_CONSTANT(QString, PLATFORM_ARM64, QStringLiteral("arm64"));
    SHARED_CONSTANT(QString, PLATFORM_ARM32, QStringLiteral("arm"));
    SHARED_CONSTANT(QString, PLATFORM_X64,   QStringLiteral("x64"));
    SHARED_CONSTANT(QString, PLATFORM_X86,   QStringLiteral("x86"));
    SHARED_CONSTANT(QString, PLATFORM_CHPE,  QStringLiteral("chpe"));
};
```

**MyApp.pro**

```
...

CONFIG += c++17 qmltypes
QML_IMPORT_NAME = MyApp
QML_IMPORT_MAJOR_VERSION = 1

...
```

**Example.qml**

```
import MyApp 1.0

Text {
    text: SharedConstants.PLATFORM_ARM64
}
```

**Example.cpp**

```
#include "SharedConstants.h"
const QString arm = SharedConstants::PLATFORM_ARM32;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can expose a value from C++ to QML as a context property using QVariant.

```
QString testStr("test");
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty(QStringLiteral("testStr"), QVariant::fromValue(testStr));
```