# Consistent definitions between QML and C++ code?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

EDIT:

Thanks very much for all of your help! But I still have a snag in my code somewhere.

I have defined a C++ class SharedConstants, which contains a Q_PROPERTY QString value and defines an Q_ENUM enum. I find that it's possible that the QString value and the enum values can be accessed from main.qml - but NOT BOTH. In particular if I *register* the C++ class, QML can access the enum values but not the QString.
So I am still missing something, but what?

Here is my C++ class:

```
/// Constants shared between C++ and QML code
class SharedConstants : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    
  enum EditState {
          Unknown,
          Pointing,
          EditRoute,
          EditPoints,
          EditOverlay
  };

  Q_ENUM(EditState)

  /// Define read-only QString property called "testString"
  Q_PROPERTY(QString testString READ getTestString)

  /// Just return a dummy string for now...
  QString getTestString() const {
      std::cout << "**** getTestString()\n";
      return QString("Dummy value");
  }
};
```

Here is my QML:

```
import SharedConstants 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    [...]
    property int editState: SharedConstants.EditRoute  // This is value of 2
    property string testString: SharedConstants.testString

    Component.onCompleted: {console.log("onCompleted");
                            console.log("editState: ", editState);
                            console.log("testString: ", testString)}
```

So I expect that when I run the app, editState = 2, and testString = “Dummy value”.

[This document](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html) indicates that a class must be registered if its enum values are to be accessed from QML. Yes, I find the SharedConstants.EditState enum values can be accessed from QML if I register SharedConstant, i.e. in main.cpp:

```
qmlRegisterType<SharedConstants>("SharedConstants", 1, 0,
                                 "SharedConstants");
```

But the Q_PROPERTY QString testString is blank/null when accessed from QML:

qml: editState:  2
qml: testString:

I find that QML *can* access testString from QML if I set a SharedConstant instance as a context property instead of registering it - i.e. in main.cpp:

```
SharedConstants constants;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("SharedConstants", &constants);
```

But in this case QML sees all SharedConstants.EditState enum values 0, as expected from documentation.

qml: editState:  0
qml: testString:  Dummy value

So I don't know why QML can see my registered C++ class enum values, but not its Q_PROPERTY values... All help much appreciated!

Comment: How about using the `enum`? By the way, it's better to define a proper slot on the *C++* side and call it from *QML* instead of using `generalSignal(string name)`. In any of these cases, you are required to change the code to handle your specific signal.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947967/can-i-use-constants-from-c-also-in-qml-files

Comment: Thanks @CemPolat, but that solution requires Qt 5.15+ - our systems are stuck at Qt 5.12 for now...

Comment: Thanks @smr - I'm trying the enum approach, but QML is sees 0 for my Q_ENUM values - see edits to my original post...

Comment: There are workflows where natural string input is required (e.g. think a prompt engine like ChatGPT), where the input string is backed by a flexible string parsing engine. Then, there are other workflows where you want to have 1:1 mapping between QML and C++. It appears from the other comments, that you're willing to transition to enums. It's worthwhile to rewrite your question to clearly express your requirements, because, as it stands there is now a mismatch between your question, the question title, and the offered answers in the comments.

Comment: Did you import SharedEnums 1.0 inside your qml file?

Comment: Ah I did not import @BahramPouryousefi - now can access C++ class enums from QML - thanks!

Comment: Thanks @StephenQuan - I changed the question title to reflect the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setContextProperty("SharedConstants", &constants)` means that you want to access `constants` in QML code. This object was created in C++ side.

`qmlRegisterType<SharedConstants>("SharedConstants", 1, 0, "SharedConstants")` means that you want QML to use a type that you define in C++. So you can't read the property(memeber variable) `testString` in QML side until you create an object of type `SharedConstants` in QML.

```cpp
qmlRegisterType<SharedConstants>("SharedConstants", 1, 0,
                                 "SharedConstants");
```

```
import SharedConstants 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    [...]
    SharedConstants {
        id: constantObject
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("onCompleted");
        
        // Get enum value defined in @SharedConstatns type
        console.log("editState: ", SharedConstants.EditRoute);

        // Get property of the object @constantObject
        console.log("testString: ", constantObject.testString)}
```